# listview with arraylist in android - each row 2 items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I fill my Array list in DB by this:

```
db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Ravi", "9100000000"));
db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Tommy", "9522222222"));
db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Karthik", "9533333333"));
```

And read (all items from DB) by this:

```
    // Reading all contacts
    List<BookMark> bookmarks = db.getAllBookMarks();
```

and I create a xml layout   listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.wepars.webapp.activity.MsgActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and also rows item  row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628831/listview-with-arraylist-simple-adapter-in-android)  before..But it works for a simple list. how can I publish my 2 diamond list in listview?

I try complete this code:

```
public class BookMarkActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);

        DatabaseBookMark db = new DatabaseBookMark(this);
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Ravi", "9100000000"));
        db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
        db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Tommy", "9522222222"));
        db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Karthik", "9533333333"));
        // Reading all contacts
        List<BookMark> bookmarks = db.getAllBookMarks();

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your **2 diamond list** in your code??? Paste the proper code.

Comment: @Clairvoyant for example, for each row I want show 'Ravi' in Textview (id=message) and '9100000000' in another Textview (id=number) ... I edited my code

Comment: Have you created the `adapter` and passing an `array` or `arraylist` to it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend an ArrayAdapter

```
public class BookmarkAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookMark> {

    public BookmarkAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<BookMark bookmark) {
        super(activity, R.layout.row_item, bookmark);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final BookMark b = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent,
                    false);
            viewHolder.message= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            viewHolder.number= (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.number);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.message.setText(b.message);
        viewHolder.number.setText(b.number);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView message, number;
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
public class BookMarkActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);

        DatabaseBookMark db = new DatabaseBookMark(this);
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Ravi", "9100000000"));
        db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
        db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Tommy", "9522222222"));
        db.addBookMark(new BookMark("Karthik", "9533333333"));
        // Reading all contacts 
        ArrayList<BookMark> bookmarks = db.getAllBookMarks();

        // ADDED
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        lv.setAdapter(new BookmarkAdapter(this,bookmarks));

    } 
}
```

Comment: Always a pleasure to helping