# OnClick on linearLayout childs not working first time

Tags: android

I have a `linearLayout` and I add some `Views` as children on it.

My sample code is:

```
 private void addChild(SampleClass s) {

      View child= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false);

      // some codes...

      child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // some codes
            });



      mainLayout.addView(child);  // mainLayout is parent LinearLayout

      child.requestFocus();

      txt.requestFocus(); // txt is a EditText out of mainLayout
 }
```

and

```
for(SampleClass s: samples){
     addChild(s);
}
```

But when for first time I click on view, `onClick` is not working but on the next I click it, it is working.

Comment: It is not so clear. Where are you taking the child from? It seems you are taking it from the layout and "re-adding" it (I think you should "inflate" it and then add it). Another thing, what kind of View is "child"? And what kind of ViewGroup is "mainLayout"?

Comment: Yes, I edited the post. view is inflate now. child and mainLayout both of them are `linearLayout`.

Comment: See the answer, another question: does child contain other views?

Comment: Post your item_layout xml please.

Comment: as best practice you have to use a listview with customadapter to add dynamically views. You can check this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31512315/2401265) old anwser of my about custom adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make *child* clickable, all layouts by default are not clickable:

```
child.setClickable(true);
```

**EDIT**
The problem seems to be the focus. It seems that the first click gives the focus to child and the second one actually clicks it.

Comment: There's no need to do that. Because `If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.` See documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Comment: You are right... the problem may be the content of child

Comment: No, Result not changed ):

Comment: Does child have the property android:focusableInTouchMode setted to true in its xml?

Comment: hmmm yes tnx. I set `child.setFocusable` to `false` after `child.requestFocus();` and this work thank you (: