# How can I convert ArrayList to ListView?

Tags: android

I'm tring to get a array from PHP page and show it in ListView.

I tried to put it in ListAdapter but this problem appears:

> 01-21 09:13:44.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.e_music/com.example.e_music.ViewArtists}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter

**Android Code:**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class ViewArtists extends ListActivity{
    // url to get all products list
    private static String urlArtists= "http://mwssong.esy.es/android/ViewArtists.php";

    // JSON Node names
    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String TAG_Artist = "Artists";
    public static final String TAG_id = "id";
    public static final String TAG_FName = "FName";

   ArrayList<Artist> getArtists =new ArrayList<Artist>();  

   class Artist {

       public String id;
       public String FName;
       public String LName;
       public String Gender;
       public String Country;      
   }

   static ArrayList<String> ResultRow;
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi") protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewartists);

        String result ="";

        try{
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mwssong.esy.es/android/ViewArtists.php");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

            try {

                BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1" ),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "error1 " + e.toString());

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag","error2 " +  e.toString());

        }

        try{
            JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data =jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //Create new Artist:
                Artist ArtistRow= new Artist();
                //Get attributes:
                ArtistRow.id=json_data.getString("id");
                ArtistRow.FName=json_data.getString("FName");
                ArtistRow.LName=json_data.getString("LName");
                ArtistRow.Gender=json_data.getString("Gender");
                ArtistRow.Country=json_data.getString("Country");

                getArtists.add(ArtistRow);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag","error3 " +  e.toString());

        }

        ArrayAdapter<Artist> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Artist>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getArtists);
        ListView myListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvArtist);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

Comment: If you format your code better it would be better for you and also for those who try to help you.

Comment: I'm asp programer.. and I'm new with android and java.. sorry for that..

Comment: Here `myListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) getArtists);` is not right way to create Adapter object . see following tutorial [How To Create A Custom Listview - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

Comment: It gave me strange things in the list view!! strange id or some thing like that!!
List of: 
com.example.e_music.ViewArtists$Artits@b3f0878

Comment: I tried this : ``
`ArrayAdapter<Artist> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Artist>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getArtists);` 
`ListView myListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvArtist);` `myListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: The values come, and I could show it in TextView..  but not in ListView

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you can't cast an `ArrayList` to a `ListAdapter`.

If you have:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You should create an adapter directly:

```
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

Then use it with:

```
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: It gave me strange things in the list view!! strange id or some thing like that!!
List of: 
com.example.e_music.ViewArtists$Artits@b3f0878

Comment: I tried this :
            `ArrayAdapter<Artist> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Artist>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getArtists);`
             `ListView myListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvArtist);`
             `myListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things - list data & list adapter. The adapter is responsible for creating views and giving them to the list, while the data is well... just data (in your case Strings).

I suggest you use an ArrayAdapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). Your code should look like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getArtists);
ListView myListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvArtist);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It gave me strange things in the list view!! strange id or some thing like that!!
List of: 
com.example.e_music.ViewArtists$Artits@b3f0878

Comment: I tried this :
    `ArrayAdapter<Artist> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Artist>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getArtists);`
     `ListView myListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvArtist);`
     `myListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: It is probably calling the toString() method of Artist. If you override this function, it should give you what you want.

Comment: class Artist { @Override public String toString() { return FName + " " + LName;}

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect the code you are using after you updated it?

Comment: I have more than column, I need class for every column or just Artist? @Doron Yakolev-Golani

Comment: I can't see where I calling the toString() method of Artist!

Comment: First thing to do is to override the toString() of Artist (the adapter is calling it). Using this, you can display all the data in a formatted manner. However, if you want a more complex view you can either use a simple adapter (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628831/listview-with-arraylist-simple-adapter-in-android) or a table view inside a scroll view. I personally prefer using adapters.

Comment: It's working now.. thanks.. I Added what you write in class Artist
`@Override public String toString() { return FName + " " + LName;}` Thanks a lot..

Comment: But I want to get "Id" field, Position isn't useful to me!

Comment: You can format the return value of toString() in any way using the data you have in the artist class. If you need a more elaborate view (more than just a string for each row), you will need more complicated adapters like I suggested before.